# Create new flutter project from existing source code

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Is it possible in Android Stduio Create new flutter project from existing source code with different project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new project then it's basically from Scratch.
But if your main focus is to use existing code with another project , then just the whole project and paste another file then Use this package [Rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) to change the Package name for Android/IOS.